# Role-based authorization system for a web application?

Tags: web-services, authorization, acl, roles, role-base-authorization

I'm currently working on designing a REST-style SQL-backed web application that is to support multiple types of user roles. I'm looking for ideas for implementing an authorization abstraction for it that's both simple and powerful.

The hierarchical roles in the system would be along the lines of:

```
superuser/admin -> group owner -> group user
```

A real world example of this system would be: "I'm a school administrator, I have teachers I manage, and they all have classes that contain students".

I'm thinking along the lines of a UNIX model, except one admin's data silo cannot overlap with another admin's. In the example above, one school should never have access to the data of another one.

- An admin role would have full superuser powers over every group and user under him.
- A group owner would only have access to the group itself and the users under it.
- There can be multiple admins for one silo of data, multiple group owners per group etc.
- Admins / group owners / users will generally not change *what they can do*, as in they abilities will pretty much fixed. The thing that will change is *what pieces of data they can act upon*.

I'm absolutely certain there have to be a few general patterns out there that I can start with and develop a custom authorization system around it that's fine-tuned to my system's needs. There's ACL, there are libraries along the lines of Rails' CanCan and I'm sure many more.

I'd love to know what my options are and what some of the trade-offs would be. Resources, readings, articles, books would be all great. It's likely I'll have to implement a Parse.com-like API for this web application (i.e. API clients can write custom queries as JSON maps and those will be translated to SQL on the backend) and it'll be extremely important to prevent unauthorized access in all sorts of different query variations.

Thank you.

P.S. Just to clarify, I'm not actually on Rails, the stack I'm using has no existing libraries for authorization, hence I need to roll my own.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the hartl tutorial to implement users and admins and user levels

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users